# Executing Function Every Second Day in Flutter (Timed)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this simple send mail function in Flutter, and I would like it to be executed (sent) for example every 48 hours. How would I go around doing that? Is there a simple way to time when it is executed? I don't think code is necessary here, but let me know if you need my send mail function (it is regular Mailer function).

Comment: Sounds like you want to execute a [cron job](https://pub.dev/packages/cron).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Timer class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html):

```
const everySecondDay = const Duration(hours: 48);
final timer = Timer.periodic(everySecondDay, (Timer t) => sendMailFunction());
```

Then cancel it when appropriate:

```
timer.cancel();
```

Comment: Oh, that's cool. Thanks a lot, that should work!